# Questions about pointer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers

i would like to link the hashnode with the node. As `hashnode` is the `Node**` (a pointer to pointer of node), hence the value of `hashnode` should be the address of node pointer (i.e. `&node`). my code is below.

However, it shows an error to me that incompatible pointer types assigning to `struct Node *` from `Node **` (aka `struct Node **`); remove &.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Hashnode
{
    int size;
    struct Node** hashnode;
}Hashtable;


typedef struct Node
{
    char* word;
    struct Node* next;
}Node;

int main(void)
{
    Node* node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->word = "Elvin";
    node->next = NULL;
    printf("First Node created successfully!...\n");

    Hashtable hasht;

    hasht.size = 10;
    hasht.hashnode = malloc(sizeof(*hasht.hashnode)*hasht.size);
    for (int i = 0; i < hasht.size; i++)
    {
        hasht.hashnode[i] = NULL;
        printf("the address of the %i hashnode is: %p\n", i, hasht.hashnode[i]);
    }
    printf("The hashtable is created successfully!...\n");

    int key = 3;
    hasht.hashnode[key] = &node;
}
```

any idea what i did wrong? What am i conceptually wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> any idea what i did wrong? What am i conceptually wrong?

Although `hashnode` is a pointer to pointer to a `struct Node`, `hashnode[key]` is only a pointer to a `struct Node`.
But `&node` is again an address (or pointer) to a pointer to a `struct Node`. So the following assignment fails:

```
hasht.hashnode[key] = &node;
```

And the compiler complains rightly.

You have to do the following:

```
hasht.hashnode[key] = node;
```

Comment: Can you explain why hashnode[key] is only a pointer to a struct Node? any tutorials i can reference? Thanks a lot for your help. I get a bit confused when it is relates to pointer to pointer.

Comment: Here is a good resource that can help you: https://www.studytonight.com/c/pointers-with-array.php

Answer (score 1):

You have `hashnode` set up as an array of pointers.  So you want to assign a pointer to a given array element, not the address of a pointer:

```
hasht.hashnode[key] = node;
```